# Google OR-Tools : Solution unable to converge for Assignment with Task Sizes using python

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I tried to elaborate on the Assignment with Task Sizes example by adding a multi-dimensional "size"(demand) and "total_size_max" .

The solution seems to decide to allocate everything to 1 worker only despite the fact that others are available. The result when run allocates everything to worker(machine 18).

Sample output :

```
Machine 18 is assigned to produce Component 0 with minimum Cycle_Time = 10000000
Machine 18 is assigned to produce Component 1 with minimum Cycle_Time = 10000000
Machine 18 is assigned to produce Component 2 with minimum Cycle_Time = 10000000
Machine 18 is assigned to produce Component 3 with minimum Cycle_Time = 10000000
Machine 18 is assigned to produce Component 4 with minimum Cycle_Time = 10000000
Machine 18 is assigned to produce Component 5 with minimum Cycle_Time = 10000000
```

Code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
import time
import numpy as np

def main():
  model = cp_model.CpModel()

  start = time.time()
  # cost = machines on rows and components on columns with least cycle_time
  cost = [[7.995722268,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,7.995722268,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,7.995722268,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,7.995722268,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.764712938,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.64179678,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.764712938,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,26.10110138,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,26.10110138,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,24.79202174,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,27.72432227,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,29.63946277,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,29.4907994,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,24.79202174,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,27.72432227,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,29.63946277,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,6.271052178,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.271052178,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.271052178,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.271052178,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.271052178,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.271052178,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.271052178,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[8.213437897,10000000,4.372568825,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.213437897,10000000,4.372568825,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.372568825,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.372568825,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.213437897,10000000,4.372568825,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.213437897,10000000,4.372568825,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.372568825,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,6.282863934,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.282863934,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.282863934,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.282863934,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.282863934,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.282863934,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.282863934,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,15.49746661,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,14.36944353,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,14.95278777,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,13.33333333,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,13.33333333,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,6.194286893,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.194286893,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.194286893,10000000,14.56521739,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.194286893,10000000,17.57157641,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.194286893,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.194286893,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.194286893,10000000,14.56521739,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[8.076237035,10000000,4.400797794,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.076237035,10000000,4.400797794,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.400797794,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.400797794,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.076237035,10000000,4.400797794,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.076237035,10000000,4.400797794,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.400797794,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[8.019304639,10000000,4.496583613,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.019304639,10000000,4.496583613,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.496583613,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.496583613,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.019304639,10000000,4.496583613,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.019304639,10000000,4.496583613,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.496583613,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,3.778990587,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,3.778990587,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,3.778990587,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,3.778990587,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,3.778990587,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,3.778990587,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,3.778990587,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,11.51228733,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,4.492667454,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.492667454,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.492667454,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,11.06301248,10000000,4.492667454,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.492667454,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.492667454,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,4.492667454,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,5.512785364,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,5.512785364,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,5.512785364,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,5.512785364,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,5.512785364,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,5.512785364,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,5.512785364,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,1.780837358,1.780837358,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,1.780837358,1.780837358,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,1.780837358,10000000,1.780837358],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,7.755011055,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,7.755011055,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,7.755011055,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,7.755011055,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,25.45422456,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,29.69460764,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,32.00169225,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,25.45422456,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,29.69460764,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,28.19319991,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,27.13193117,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,26.59704717,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,28.19319991,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,27.13193117,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,21.5723175,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,21.5723175,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,21.5723175,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,21.5723175,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,21.5723175,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,21.5723175,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,21.5723175,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,8.455696203,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.455696203,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.455696203,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.455696203,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.455696203,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.455696203,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,8.455696203,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000],
[10000000,6.776314217,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.776314217,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.776314217,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.776314217,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.776314217,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.776314217,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,6.776314217,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000]
]

  #costList = [round(x) for x in cost]
  costlist = np.round(cost).astype(int).tolist()

  # demand for each component
  demand = [28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,56,28,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,60,176,176,176,176,176,176,176,176,176,352,194,194,194,194,194,194,194,194,194,388,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,112,56,149,149,149,149,149,149,149,149,149,298,911,911,911,911,911,911,911,911,911,1822]

  # convert to numpy array for division
  arr = np.array(cost)
  # total available hours
  available_hrs = 2592000
  total_size_max =  available_hrs / arr
  total_size_max = total_size_max.astype(int)

  num_workers = len(cost)
  num_tasks = len(cost[1])
  # Variables
  x = []
  for i in range(num_workers):
    t = []
    for j in range(num_tasks):
      t.append(model.NewIntVar(0, 1, "x[%i,%i]" % (i, j)))
    x.append(t)
  x_array = [x[i][j] for i in range(num_workers) for j in range(num_tasks)]

  # Constraints

  # Each component is assigned to at least one machine.
  [model.Add(sum(x[i][j] for i in range(num_workers)) >= 1)
  for j in range(num_tasks)]

  # Total demand of component for each machine is at most total_size_max(available_hrs/cycle_time).
  [model.Add(sum(demand[j] * x[i][j] for j in range(num_tasks)) <= total_size_max[i][j])
  for i in range(num_workers)]
  model.Minimize(sum([np.dot(x_row, cost_row) for (x_row, cost_row) in zip(x, costlist)]))
  solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
  status = solver.Solve(model)

  if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    print('Minimum cost = %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
    print()

    for i in range(num_workers):

      for j in range(num_tasks):

        if solver.Value(x[i][j]) == 1:
          print('Machine ', i, ' is assigned to produce Component ', j, ' with minimum Cycle_Time = ', cost[i][j])
    print()
    end = time.time()
    print("Time = ", round(end - start, 4), "seconds")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I took this from the sample example and tweaked input data according to my need. Can someone help resolve this issue?

Expected result is that the machine with lowest time should be assigned according to the demand

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full answer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Sep 14 00:52:54 2019

@author: 320048504
"""

from __future__ import print_function

from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
import time
import numpy as np


def main():
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    start = time.time()
    cost = [[
        7.995722268, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 7.995722268, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 7.995722268, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 7.995722268, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
    ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.764712938, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, 6.64179678, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, 6.764712938, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 26.10110138, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, 26.10110138, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 24.79202174, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 27.72432227, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 29.63946277, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                29.4907994, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 24.79202174,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 27.72432227, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 29.63946277, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, 6.271052178, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 6.271052178, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                6.271052178, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.271052178,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.271052178, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.271052178, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.271052178, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                8.213437897, -1, 4.372568825, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                8.213437897, -1, 4.372568825, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 4.372568825, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                4.372568825, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.213437897, -1,
                4.372568825, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.213437897, -1,
                4.372568825, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4.372568825,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, 6.282863934, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 6.282863934, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                6.282863934, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.282863934,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.282863934, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.282863934, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.282863934, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 15.49746661, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 14.36944353, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 14.95278777, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13.33333333, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13.33333333, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, 6.194286893, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 6.194286893, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                6.194286893, -1, 14.56521739, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                6.194286893, -1, 17.57157641, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                6.194286893, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                6.194286893, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.194286893,
                -1, 14.56521739, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                8.076237035, -1, 4.400797794, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                8.076237035, -1, 4.400797794, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 4.400797794, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                4.400797794, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.076237035, -1,
                4.400797794, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.076237035, -1,
                4.400797794, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4.400797794,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                8.019304639, -1, 4.496583613, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                8.019304639, -1, 4.496583613, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 4.496583613, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                4.496583613, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.019304639, -1,
                4.496583613, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.019304639, -1,
                4.496583613, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4.496583613,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 3.778990587, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, 3.778990587, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                3.778990587, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3.778990587,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3.778990587, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3.778990587, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 3.778990587, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                11.51228733, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, 4.492667454, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                4.492667454, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4.492667454,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 11.06301248, -1, 4.492667454, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4.492667454, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4.492667454, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, 4.492667454, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5.512785364, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5.512785364, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, 5.512785364, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                5.512785364, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5.512785364,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5.512785364, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5.512785364, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1.780837358, -1, 1.780837358,
                1.780837358, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1.780837358, -1,
                1.780837358, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1.780837358, -1,
                1.780837358, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1.780837358, -1,
                1.780837358, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1.780837358, -1,
                1.780837358, 1.780837358, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                1.780837358, -1, 1.780837358, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                1.780837358, -1, 1.780837358
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 7.755011055, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, 7.755011055, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 7.755011055, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, 7.755011055, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 25.45422456, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 29.69460764, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 32.00169225, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 25.45422456, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 29.69460764, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 28.19319991, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 27.13193117, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 26.59704717, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 28.19319991, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 27.13193117, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, 21.5723175, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                21.5723175, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 21.5723175, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 21.5723175, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 21.5723175, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 21.5723175, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 21.5723175,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, 8.455696203, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                8.455696203, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.455696203,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.455696203, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.455696203, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 8.455696203, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 8.455696203, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ],
            [
                -1, 6.776314217, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                6.776314217, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.776314217,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.776314217, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.776314217, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.776314217, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 6.776314217, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
            ]]

    scaling = 100
    int_cost = [[int(round(x * scaling)) for x in line] for line in cost]

    # demand for each component
    demand = [
        28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 56, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30,
        30, 30, 60, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 352, 194, 194,
        194, 194, 194, 194, 194, 194, 194, 388, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56,
        56, 112, 56, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 298, 911,
        911, 911, 911, 911, 911, 911, 911, 911, 1822
    ]

    # total available hours
    available_hrs = 2592000

    num_workers = len(int_cost)
    num_tasks = len(int_cost[1])
    print('num_workers =', num_workers, ', num_tasks =', num_tasks)

    # Variables
    x = [[
        0 if int_cost[i][j] < 0 else model.NewBoolVar('x[%i,%i]' % (i, j))
        for j in range(num_tasks)
    ] for i in range(num_workers)]

    # Constraints

    # For each component, demand is met.
    for j in range(num_tasks):
        model.Add(
            sum(x[i][j] for i in range(num_workers)
                if int_cost[i][j] >= 0) == 1)

    # Total worked hours for each machine is at most available_hrs.
    for i in range(num_workers):
        model.Add(
            sum(x[i][j] * int_cost[i][j] * demand[j] for j in range(num_tasks)
                if int_cost[i][j] >= 0) <= available_hrs * scaling)

    # Objective: minimize worked hours.
    model.Minimize(
        sum(x[i][j] * int_cost[i][j] * demand[j] for i in range(num_workers)
            for j in range(num_tasks) if int_cost[i][j] >= 0))
    model.Proto().objective.scaling_factor = 1.0 / scaling

    # Solve.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
    solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8
    status = solver.Solve(model)

    # Print solution.
    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
        print('Minimum cost = %f' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
        print()

        for i in range(num_workers):

            for j in range(num_tasks):
                qty = 0 if cost[i][j] == -1 else solver.Value(x[i][j])
                if qty > 0:
                    print('Machine ', i, ' is assigned to produce Component ',
                          j, ' with minimum Cycle_Time = ', cost[i][j])
        print()
        end = time.time()
        print("Time = ", round(end - start, 4), "seconds")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have added cost scaling to improve precision

Here is the output:

```
Minimum cost = 123887.560000

Machine  0  is assigned to produce Component  0  with minimum Cycle_Time =  7.995722268
Machine  0  is assigned to produce Component  11  with minimum Cycle_Time =  7.995722268
...
Machine  24  is assigned to produce Component  53  with minimum Cycle_Time =  6.776314217
Machine  24  is assigned to produce Component  63  with minimum Cycle_Time =  6.776314217

Time =  0.0834 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1578

If you cross-post, please indicate it.

Thanks

Comment: how would the constraints be setup if the objective is changes to Maximising the demand until it is met, could you help ?

Comment: @lperron - could you help here ?

Comment: I do not understand the new objective.

Comment: Instead of minimizing the effective utilization (x[i][j] * int_cost[i][j] * demand[j] ), how do we put DEMAND as the objective and ensure it is met (solution <= demand) most effectively.

in current example, we are minimizing the usage of machines/workers, what do we need to do to change it to have a MET Demand objective.

this is so because there could be cases when demand is not 100% met, so the above solution doesnt gives us a result. So we would want to optimize and meet as much as possible.

Comment: Can you write the exact equation of the objective ?

Comment: @lperron - I have put the details below as constraint and obejctive :

Constraint-1:
there should be fewer/no unmet demand left.

Constraint-2:
Cost of running machines should be least : Demand*cycle-time

Constraint-3:
Total availability of machine & moulds should not exceed.

Constraint-4 :
Feasible components - which machine, mould can component be made on (using cycle-time matrix) 

Constraint-5:
Maximise demand until it is met.
 
Objective :
minimize(COST of making components based on above constraints)

Comment: @lperron - 
could you also suggest how will we minimize an objective (lets say if we penalize by a value of 10 for each usage of a machine and our final objective is to minimize the cost/penalty).
this doesnt work :
    # Objective: minimize cost (wrt penalty)
        model.Maximize(
            sum(x[i][j] * penalty1 for i in range(num_workers)
                     if int_cost[i][j] >= 0) )